# Why are exponential sums so bad at solving this very easy problem?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, exponential-sums

Exponential sums are a powerful tool in additive combinatorics and number theory. In my understanding, when it comes to estimate the cardinality of a certain set, exponential sums are (essentially) used in this way: (1) the indicator function of the set is replaced by an appropriate exponential sum; (2) the sum of the indicator function and the sum of the exponential sum are swapped; (3) the main term is extracted; 4) the error term is bounded.

However, recently I stumble upon some simple additive problems for which the exponential-sums approach seems to fail miserably. My (somehow philosophical) question is: Am I applying exponential sums in the wrong way? (And, in such a case, how should apply them to solve such problems?) Or are exponential sums are not good for these problems? (And, in such a case, what is the reason it is so?)

Below an extremely simple example in which exponential sums seem to fails. Of course, I do not really care about solving such problem with exponential sums, but it is just for the sake of example.

Let $1 \leq h \leq m$ be fixed integers. We want to estimate the number $C$ of $(x, y) \in \{0,\dots,h-1\}^2$ such that $x \equiv y \bmod m$. Obviously, $C = h$. Proceeding with exponential sums, we have:
$$C = \sum_{0 \leq x < h} \sum_{0 \leq y < h} \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x \equiv y \bmod m \\ 0 & \text{ if not} \end{cases}$$
$$\stackrel{(1)}{=} \sum_{0 \leq x < h} \sum_{0 \leq y < h} \frac1{m} \sum_{0 \leq k < m} \exp\Big(\frac{2 \pi i (x - y)k}{m}\Big)$$
$$\stackrel{(2)}{=} \frac1{m} \sum_{0 \leq k < m} \sum_{0 \leq x < h} \sum_{0 \leq y < h} \exp\Big(\frac{2 \pi i (x - y)k}{m}\Big)$$
$$\stackrel{(3)}{=} ???$$
In step (3) comes the problem. It is not clear what the main term of $\sum_{0 \leq k <m}$ is. The term $k = 0$ surely is not, since it equals $h^2 / m$. In fact, all the terms are positive an equal to $|\sum_{0 \leq x < h} \exp\Big(\frac{2 \pi i x k}{m}\Big))|^2$.
One can compute explicitly all the geometric sums and get the result, but that is unwieldy.

Comment: One possible (unsatisfying) answer: The method of an exponential sums is a way to give a new formula for a quantity that you already have a formula for. Sometimes, this formula is easier to study than the original, and we use the formula. Other times, it's harder to study, and we don't.

Comment: As Will says, exponential sums convert one type of counting problem into another. For example, bounding the error term often uses as an ingredient the fact that we can bound the $L^2$ norm of a Fourier expression efficiently, via Parseval - but Parseval is proved using the fact that we can count solutions to the binary equation $x-y=0$, using non-Fourier methods (otherwise it would be circular). 

So it's better to think of exponential sums as a process that converts one discrete/additive/combinatorial problem into another (or a few different other sub-problems), which are hopefully easier.

Comment: for this specific problem, the wrong estimate $h^2/m$ appears if you replace the sums over $x$ and $y$ by integrals, which would be allowed if $k\ll m$, but the third sum over $k$ goes all the way up to $k=m-1$ so that breaks.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker for $k = 0$ the sums over $x,y$ have all addends equal to $1$ and so they amount to $h \cdot h = h^2$. Not integral involved.

Comment: Since this is an extremely simple example, can you tell the answer obtained by another method? Or would you actually be happy to have an estimate this way?

Comment: @ShannonStarr the answer is $C = h$, by direct counting.

Comment: @ThomasBloom I see. Do you know if there is some general heuristic to see if there is some hope that the "conversion" leads to a simpler problem? Something like: "...for additive problems of this kind... exponential sums are well-known to be of no help"

Comment: A lot of times you do calculate explicitly, in this case to get $m^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \left(\sin(\pi kh/m)/\sin(\pi k/m)\right)^2$. You can write it using Fejer's kernel as $h \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} F_h(\pi x_k) \Delta x$ where $x_k = k/m$ and $\Delta x=1/m$. The fact that the average of $F_h$ is 1 on its domain $[-\pi,\pi]$ does give the correct order-of-magnitude, though you may be concerned about an error of approximation in the Riemann sum rather than the integral. But apparently the sum gives the exact formula, for $h\leq m$, as you have verified.

Comment: @ShannonStarr I think your comment could be an answer, maybe giving more details on the integral approximation of the sum. Essentially, you are showing that exponential sums work for this problem

Comment: @locra I think you are discovering a new identity. I do not know if it is a known identity or not. There are identities for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos(nx)$ for instance. It seems like your identity might be an example of a character relation. It is definitely related to viewing the $\ell^2$ norm by two different decompositions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic example of exponential sums in Number Theory is to count solutions to an equation such as $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\equiv 0$ $\mod p$ where $p$ is prime this is because $p$-adic solutions are a necessary condition for solutions in integers and also for getting methods like the [Hardy_Littlewood circle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_circle_method) to work. Essentially this is an example of the [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle) - local solutions give a global solution in certain circumstances.

In this case the main term from your exponential sum, given by setting $k=0$ in your problem, is the average number of solutions in the following sense. Pick values for the $x_i$'s ranging over all values $\mod p$. This gives $p^n$ possible values for $f$. We now make the assumption that these values are approximately evenly distributed $\mod p$. It then makes sense that $p^n/p=p^{n-1}$ should be a good estimate for the total number of solutions to the congruence $f\equiv 0$.

The method of exponential sums then proceeds by showing that the error term given by the rest of the sum is small in comparison with the main term and this gives you solutions for large enough $p$. The classical example of this is for diagonal equations $a_1x_1^k+\cdots +a_nx_n^k \equiv 0$. (Andre Weil analysed these in his paper where he stated the famous [Weil Conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures))

You can also use similar ideas to solve equations over restricted sets of variables. In your case case, $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1-x_2$ solving $\mod m$ with a set $\{0,\cdots h-1\}$. The same idea gives you a main term of $h^2/m$. The problem is you don't have equi-distribution for the number of solutions of $x_1-x_2=r$ as $r$ varies unless $h$ is almost the same size as $m$ and in that case $h^2/m\approx h$ giving you an accurate estimate of the number of solution.

In this case of large $h$ the error term is also small so the standard approach of exponential sums does actually work.

Note that the reason why exponential sums breaks down is because the fourier coefficients of  your set $\{0,\cdots h-1\}$ are not small if $h$ is small compared to $m$.

We can relate this to a classic example from additive combinatorics - Roth's Theorem for arithmetic progressions of length 3. we have $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1-2x_2+x_3$ and the exponential sum method allows us to count length 3 aps $\mod n$  where x_i are taken from sets $A,B,C$ which are reasonably dense in $\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Then we can express the solution count in the same way with the main term being $|A|B||C|/n$ and the error term a sum of fourier coefficients of the characteristic functions, $N^2\sum_{s} \widetilde{A}(s) \widetilde{B}(-2s) \widetilde{C}(s)$. If the fourier coefficients are small indicating that the sets are uniformly distributed in a certain sense, often called pseudo-random, then we can show that the error term is small and solutions exist.

Again, the above does not work if the sets are not sufficiently pseudo-random for the main term to approximate the number of solutions and in this case one has to use alternative ideas to show that a set with a large fourier coefficient is not uniformly distributed and hence concentrated in some arithmetic progression $\mod m$ which allows one to iterate. This is described very elegantly in Tim Gowers' papers on [Szemeredi's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem).

Others know these ideas much better than I do! I just wanted to give some background and note the importance of pseudo-randomness in the standard number theoretic application of exponential sums but also that if this fails there are techniques that one can apply to deal with the case where the sets are more structured.

Comment: "The problem is you don't have equi-distribution for the number of solutions of $x_1 - x_2 = r$ as $r$ varies unless $h$ is almost the same size as $m$." Alright, I think this is the key point,